# How to send a daily report with Heroku's scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, actionmailer, scheduler

I'm trying to use heroku's scheduler and a rake task to send myself a daily report.

In scheduler.rake I have

```
task :send_report => :environment do
  user_count = User.count
  share_count = Share.count
  ReportMailer.send(user_count, share_count).deliver
end
```

My ReportMailer looks something like this

```
class ReportMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def send(user_count, share_count)
    @user_count = user_count
    @share_count = share_count
    mail(from: "email@example.com", to: "email@spam.com", subject: "Report")
  end
end
```

And the view send.html.erb I have

```
<p>Report</p>
<p>Users: <%= @user_count %></p>
<p>Shares: <%= @share_count %></p>
```

I'm getting an error when I run `heroku run rake send_report`

```
Sending report...
   (1.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" 
   (1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "shares" 
rake aborted!
2 is not a symbol
/app/lib/tasks/scheduler.rake:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => send_report
```

User.count = 2 so I'm assuming I have to pass the 'counts' in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send` is a method [defined](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-send) by `Object`. Rename your mailer action.

Comment: Great. Sorted it out. Thanks!